# XMLReader won't read large file

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I'm having a problem with a really large XML (16G).

I'm using php's XMLReader to import some data in my database from several (large) XML's. The files are local and I can't use anything else but XML. I wrote a script that does it's job quite well and imports XML's with 1 or 2 million items (it imports the file in smaller pieces and then jumps to the last imported item), but I have a problem with a really big XML which has about 10 million items. XMLReader simply won't open that XML. It gives me this error:

```
PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data in ...
```

Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot

Adi Ulici

Comment: Both "really" and "large" is undefined. Please make your question more specific.

Comment: "has about 10 million items". It's 16G. Thanks for your point

Comment: Did you look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/6370240/765890

Comment: I tried increasing the memory limit, didn't worked..

Comment: Are you running 32-bit or 64-bit PHP?

Comment: If it's 32-bit PHP, I'd guess that any file extensions (including XML_Reader) are also 32-bit and limited by 32-bit file pointers and equivalent: 32-bit can't handle a file of that size. Test it with a 64-bit server running 64-bit PHP

Comment: Do you have the file on disc or in a remote location? Also please add a little bit of code (e.g. the lines around where that warning is produced). If you try with a smaller file at the same location, does it work? At which size does it stop working?

Comment: It gives me the error right here: `$xml->open($xmlSrc, "UTF-8");`
Smaller files at the same location work. I think Mark Baker may be right..

Comment: Did you finally find a solution?

Comment: @RaulPinto I really don't remember. If I remember correctly Mark Baker's answer was right, and the file was too large for being handled on that particular configuration. Sorry I can't help more